# can not resolve spring cloud dependency when just import spring-boot-dependencies as pom

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-cloud

Version:
springboot-2.0.0.RELEASE
springcloud-Finchley.RC1

My project depend on spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client,
when I declare spring-boot-starter-parent as the parent like below,Idea can resovle the version of eureka-client,

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

but when i import spring-boot-dependencies as pom like below ,Idea can not resovle the version of eureka-client,
why?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The spring-boot-starter-parent-2.0.0.RELEASE.pom file almost only import spring-boot-dependencies at the head

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath>../../spring-boot-dependencies</relativePath>
</parent>
```

plus,I import spring cloud like below

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>Finchley.RC1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: That is the documented way to use spring cloud. Spring boot knows nothing about it.

Comment: I updated my question,the spring-boot-starter-parent-2.0.0.RELEASE.pom file almost only import spring-boot-dependencies at the head of the file,so I think the two way should be both OK.

Comment: Hey, have you found a solution at the end? I search this problem and hit here, a year later when this was post, still see no solution. lol

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put the spring-cloud-dependencies into the dependencyManagement block like this:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```